# Running jupyter notebook from web server on ipad localhost

Tags: ios, ssh, localhost, jupyter-notebook, digital-ocean

I'm using Blink on my iPad Pro to SSH to my DigitalOcean Ubuntu web server and run Jupyter Notebook.

I can SSH just fine, and can run Jupyter Notebook fine as well. I get the usual Jupyter Notebook url http://localhost:8888/?token-12345 but when copy-pasting this url in my chrome browser on my iPad, I get he error message 'this site can't be reached'.

Anyone knows how to fix that? Is SSH tunnelling part of the solution? What command(s) should I run?

Comment: When you say localhost, which means it is specific to that particular machine. So that replace localhost with your IP address, it may help you to launch the jupyter notbook

Comment: yes, on chrome on the iPad I've tried to replace 'localhost' in the url with my server's IP address, without success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that:

- **SSH tunnel / port forwarding**. You may need a standalone app to establish a tunnel ([this one](https://itunes.apple.com/app/ssh-tunnel/id1260223542?mt=8), for example), and then connect to your server in browser using localhost and mapped port.
- **Public server**. You can make your server accessible publicly (more details [here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html)), but beware that you may also need to configure a valid SSL certificate to connect to your server via HTTPS, or otherwise Jupyter's kernel will not be able to connect in any iOS browser. Here is a step-by-step guide on how to configure a self-signed certificate that will work on iPad: https://juno.sh/ssl-self-signed-cert/

Finally, once you get it working in Chrome/Safari, you may consider using an app that I've developed instead of browser, it's called **Juno** and it's a Jupyter Notebook client for iPad: https://itunes.apple.com/app/juno-jupyter-notebook-client/id1315744137

It does require an in-app purchase to connect to an arbitrary server, but you can launch a bunch of introductory notebooks for free out of the box, without any configuration.

Comment: Thanks - I've installed Juno yesterday, but can't connect to my server's IP. I'm not sure which steps I'm missing when configuring my server...

Comment: Ah great! Sounds like you are trying to go down the SSH tunnel route; I'm not sure if Blink allows port forwarding, so you may need an app that does exactly that. Once you configure the tunnel providing your keys and map your server's 8888 port to, say, 8889 local port on your iPad, you can access Jupyter Notebook using localhost:8889 as server's address in both browser and Juno. Feel free to reach out to contact@juno.sh if you have any issues!

Comment: Are port forwarding features of apps like Termius enough for the job?it would seems yes to me.

Comment: @RhoPhi Yes, it should be enough. I haven't tried it specifically with Termius, but it works fine with other similar apps: just add a custom server in Juno with localhost and mapped port as server address.

Comment: Not clear how to do this using the provided app I.e. The ow to use ssh tunnel plus safari.   I can use Textastic to open a ssh to start the session then Juno ssh tunnel to do it.  Just wonder how to do this using iOS + ssh tunneling as the original question here.